# How to create Reusable Android BottomSheet Presentation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a bunch of popup Dialogs throughout the app I'm working on. What I wanted to do is turn them all into a `BottomSheet` presentation. Right now, I have one class where I'm instantiating the Dialogs from and able to reuse them throughout the app.

What would I need to do: to do the same to be able to reuse `BottomSheetDialogFragments`? Rather than creating a `BottomSheet` presentation from a screen to screen basis, is there a way to have all of them in one class and just call them when I need to from a different screen?

Adding a little bit more context. Let's say I have a CloseDialog, LogoutConfirmationDialog and I use them on multiple screens currently. I would like to do the same with the Android BottomSheet presentation modal if I was to turn these two Dialogs into a BottomSheet presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom fragment and inherit "BottomSheetDialogFragment"

```
class CustomBtmSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() 
    {

    
            override fun onCreateView(
                inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                savedInstanceState: Bundle?
            ): View? 
            {
                return inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_dialog,
                    container,
                    false
                )
            }



            override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialog

            override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
                BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)

            override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

                dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

            }


    }
```